# How to remove focus and selection from Listbox with a single "Click"?

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("500x300")

def update(data):    
# Clear the listbox
    my_list.delete(0, END)

# Add toppings to listbox
    for item in data:
        my_list.insert(END, item)

def fillout(e):  # $$%%$$%%$$

    my_entry.delete(0, END)
    my_entry.insert(0, my_list.get(ANCHOR))

    my_list .selection_clear(0, END)  
    my_entry .focus_set()                     
    my_entry .icursor(END)                   

def check(e): 

    typed = my_entry.get()

    if typed == '':
        data = toppings
    else:
        data = []
        for item in toppings:
            if typed.lower() in item.lower():
                data.append(item)
    update(data)                


my_label = Label(root, text="Start", fg="grey")
my_label.pack(pady=20)

my_entry = Entry(root)
my_entry.pack()

my_list = Listbox(root, width=50)
my_list.pack(pady=40)

toppings = ["Pepperoni", "Peppers", "Mushrooms", "Cheese", "Onions"]

my_list.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>", fillout)
my_entry.bind("<KeyRelease>", check)

root.mainloop()
```

I am trying to remove the focus and deselect the widget (listbox) to the entry. In short, the behavior I want is that when selecting an option from the list box, remove all kinds of focus and instantly the insertion cursor is in the input. I've tried with (.focus_set () and selection_clear ()), but it doesn't seem to work for me. I ask for your help and guidance please. Thanks for taking the time to read this...!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wait to set the focus until after all other pending events have been processed. You can do that by using `after_idle`, like in the following example:

```
my_entry.after_idle(my_entry.focus_set)
```

Comment: It seems this is what I was looking for. Thanks very much buddy.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `"<<ListboxSelect>>"` event will do the selection after your event handler.

I didn't find a good way for it, so a stupid way here.

```py
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("500x300")

def select(e):

    selection = my_list.get(ANCHOR)
    my_list.selection_clear(0, END)
    root.after(100, fillout, selection)

def fillout(selection):

    my_entry.focus_set()
    my_entry.delete(0, END)
    my_entry.insert(0, selection)
    my_entry.icursor(END)


def check(e):

    typed = my_entry.get()

    if typed == '':
        data = toppings
    else:
        data = []
        for item in toppings:
            if typed.lower() in item.lower():
                data.append(item)
    update(data)


my_label = Label(root, text="Start", fg="grey")
my_label.pack(pady=20)

my_entry = Entry(root)
my_entry.pack()

selection = ''
toppings = ("Pepperoni", "Peppers", "Mushrooms", "Cheese", "Onions")
my_list = Listbox(root, width=50)
my_list.pack(pady=40)
my_list.insert(0, *toppings)

my_list.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>", select)
my_entry.bind("<KeyRelease>", check)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: It seems to work thanks, but I have to ask without global this behavior cannot be achieved?

Comment: @MarcoCizneros it can be passed as an argument to the function that uses it, especially easy because the function that calls the one that will use the argument also creates it

Comment: @Matiiss Good point, so I would avoid using `global`, but between using this method or using `after_idle()`, which one should I use if we are talking about `performance` or lower `memory` usage?

Comment: @MarcoCizneros I think both methods are extremely close in terms of memory and performance (either how they are close enough for that to not matter), the only real difference is that for one you can set a specific time, the other will be called after all the other tasks have been processed which seems to be what you need